# Proving two integers are relatively prime using Bezout's Theorem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, prime-numbers

If $\operatorname{gcd}(a, b) = 1,$ $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime and also if $\operatorname{gcd}(a, b)$ is equal to $1$ there should be $2$ integers $k$ and $m$ such that $ak + bm = 1.$

If we can find such integers k and m, is it a proof that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime ?

What you think about that proof? Is it correct way?

Comment: A proof of *what*?

Comment: Is it proof that a and b are relatively prime if there exists 2 integers k and m such that k.a + m.b = 1

Comment: This is not a proof. Basically you are asking for a proof.

Comment: Assume a = 5n+2 and b = 8n+3. Saying k = 8 and m = -5 isnt enough to prove they are relatively prime? Because 8(5n+2)-5(8n+3) = 1. I know it can be proved by Euclidean algorithm but I just wonder is finding 2 integers is enough to prove.

Answer (score 2):

$a, b$ be two integers and suppose there exists two integers $u, v$ such that $$au+bv=1$$

Claim: $a, b$ are relatively prime or co-prime.

Suppose, $ gcd(a,b)= d$

So, $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$ .

$d|a$ and $d|b$ .

Hence, $d|au+bv =1$

$d\in\{-1, 1\}$

As, $d$ is the greatest common divisor implies $d=1$.

Hence, $gcd(a, b) =1$

Comment: This even is reversible, by the Euclidean algorithm!